# Waiting for a positive response (from a server)

Tags: c#, timer, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Following the good ideas that I was given in my previous question on  [how to wait for processes to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281620/using-a-timer-to-wait-for-processes-to-complete/51282349#51282349) I would like to ask something related.

This time I don't have two processes to do one after another, but only one process that has to proceed *after* it gets a positive response from a server. Something like this

```
private async Task<bool> requestPermission()
{
    var result = await sendRequestToServer();
    return result;
}

private async Task Process1()
{ bool amIOktoGo=false;
   amIOktoGo= await requestPermission();
   while(!amIOktoGo)
   {
      await Task.Delay(1000);
     amIOktoGo= await requestPermission();
    } 

   
  //Finally! Do some more stuff involving awaits and requests from the server

}
```

Again, this seems overly complicated. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @bommelding  winforms

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There is a library [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) which supports exactly the scenario for retry

Here's an async example for your case. If there is an exception or result returned `false`, it retries your action async.

```
await Policy
  .Handle<Exception>()
  .OrResult<bool>(b => !b)
  .WaitAndRetry(new[]
  {
     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
  })
  .RetryAsync()
  .ExecuteAsync(() => requestPermission());
```

Comment: does the code posted includes a waiting time? (in my case 1 sec)

Comment: @KansaiRobot you can check by yourself the library. I found they have a waiting time too. Look at my answer updated